# asp:Button stopped working without changing the code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm stuck on this error and I cannot figure it out why is happening. I took a look on the web in order to find something helpfull but there is nothing specific about my case, at least I couldn't find it.

---

***Error:***

> CS1061: 'beaulard21_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Btn_submit_Click' and no extension method 'Btn_submit_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'beaulard21_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

---

***Snippet where the error occurs:***

```html
<form>
  <div class='form-group'>
   <input name='email' type='email' class='form-control' id='emailCliente' placeholder='Email' runat='server'>
 </div>
 <div class='form-group'>
  <input name='name' type='text' class='form-control' id='nomeCliente' placeholder='Nome' runat='server'>
  </div>
 <div class='form-group'>
    <textarea name='comment' class='form-control' rows='5' id='messaggio' placeholder='Messaggio (opzionale)' runat='server'></textarea>
 </div>
 <!-- Error is thrown in the next line --> 
 <asp:Button id='BtnInvia' Text='Invia' CssClass='btn btn-secondary' OnClick='Btn_submit_Click' runat='server'/>
</form>
```

***My code behind function***:

```
private void Btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //EMAIL SENDING ALGORITHM
}
```

---

***Remarks***

I have the same form with the same button and the same IDs in other 2 pages, and currently they work perfectly. Yesterday this page was also working without any issues and I didn't change anything. I'm not getting the point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the button and the code behind and then make a rebuild for your solution and then create it again.
sometimes caching in VS makes some unexpected problems!

I hope this will helpful for you!

Comment: You're Welcome :D

Answer (score 1):

- Ensure you don't have any other errors or warnings.
- Try to remove event handler name in your HTML and generate it again using Visual Studio. Then check if it appears in the same code-behind file you looked before.

Comment: I don't have any error or warning when I compile the solution. Now I'm trying the second point you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I chose the other answer as solution because it was more accurate for my case. Anyway you deserve an upvote for sure. Thanks alot